# What navigator.plugins is evaluated to in JavaScript in IE?

Tags: javascript

The book *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers* gives the following code for detecting if a plugin is installed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//check plugins in non-IE browser
function hasPlugin(name) {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//check plugins in IE
function hasIePlugin(name) {
    try {
        new ActiveXObject(name);
        return true;
    } catch (ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

//check if the flash plugin exists in a browser
function hasFlash() {
    var result = hasPlugin("Flash");
    if (!result) {
        result = hasIePlugin("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
    }

    return result;
}
</script>
```

The **hasPlugin** function will return false in IE and **navigator.plugins.length** is used in a for loop, so I wonder what **navigator.plugins** is evaluated to in IE. I ran the following code in IE8:

```
alert(navigator.plugins); //return [object]
alert(navigator.plugins.length); //return 0
alert(navigator.plugins === null); //return false
alert(navigator.plugins === undefined); //return false

//check if it is an empty object
var i = 0;

for (var key in navigator.plugins) {
    ++i;
}

alert(i); //return 1
```

**navigator.plugins** is not evaluated to null, undefined and it has one element, but its length is 0. So what exactly **navigator.plugins** is evaluated to in IE?

Comment: I don't have access to old IE versions, but you might want to try using `console.log` instead of `alert` in order to get more useful information.

Comment: @4castle already tried `console.log`, but the IE developer tool output the same result as the `alert` command.

Comment: Try putting `console.log(key, navigator.plugins[key]);` inside your loop.

Comment: if navigator.plugins.length === 0, then there are no plugins - but the navigator.plugins obejct will still exist